# ADBannerViewDelegate didFailToReceiveAdWithError continuously calling

Tags: ios, ios9, adbannerview

I am facing this issue since iOS 9 release.

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Following error occurs-

> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=8 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo={ADInternalErrorCode=8, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Frame load interrupted}

Comment: Hi, Do you have any answer for this?

Comment: No, just changed to admob

Comment: Yes I already did same. By the way thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

This delegate is repeatedly called because apple has discontinued iADs from june 30th. SO developers may not be able to integrate iADS from now. ADMOB is the alternative.